# Microsoft C/C++ compiler switch needed for local variable declaration placement

Tags: c, windows, variables, compiler-construction, declaration

I'm compiling some C files using Microsoft C/C++ and it's complaining about declaring local variables inside a block.  Declaring them at the beginning of a block, of course, is fine.  What compiler switch can I use to suppress the errors that I'm getting?

Much appreciated,

kris

Answer (score 5):

In C89 and earlier, all block-scope variable declarations must come before any statements.  C99 changed this rule, so that declarations and statements may be intermixed as in C++.

Unfortunately, Microsoft has chosen not to support C99 in Visual Studio and has no plans to AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

In standard C, you can't declare variables anywhere but at the beginning. This is different from C++ where variables can be declared anywhere.

So you must compile the files as if they were C++ via `/TP`.

See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181506) for more details.

Comment: In C99, you can. Microsoft just decided not to support it.

Comment: I really wish that even if they still didn't support C99 that MS would bring at least this one part of it over to C as an 'extension'.  Hey - they did for "//" comments!

Comment: @Michael whilst they're at it they could bring over `inline` functions, which are implemented in MSVC2010 C++ but not C. Confused face.

Comment: @Michael: Whoa... what's special about the `//` comments? I'd never heard of that one!

Comment: @Lambert: Single-line comments common and standard in C++, but weren't in C until C99 (but most compilers, even those that generally don't support C99, support it anyway).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, It's not funny when you break the daily build after a week because of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CL.exe /Tpfilename
```

It means "compile as C++ regardless of the extension".

Or, to put it another way, what you're doing is illegal in C, so of course it complains. Either change it to C++ or force it to be read as C++.

Comment: mixing code and declarations hasn't been illegal in C for more than 10 years - it's just that MS chose not to support newer revisions of the C standard

Answer (score 0):

You can use /TP to force the compiler to compile them as C++ files.  I'm not sure if this is what you want, however.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me, I tried it before I posted my question.